# Statement not returning the correct number or rows

Tags: sql

Why is the first statement not returning the number of the 2nd?

```
select random_selection.randnum,
   random_selection.createddate,
   random_selection.ozip3, 
   random_selection.boxid, 
   random_selection.boxaddr, 
   random_selection.locdesc, 
   random_selection.loccity, 
   random_selection.lastmf,
   random_selection.lastsat,
   random_selection.boxtype,
   random_selection.svcclas,
   random_selection.dropzip5,
   dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id
from random_selection, dropper_city_brk_2
where random_selection.ozip3 = dropper_city_brk_2.zip3
and dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id <> 10002
and random_selection.dropper_id is null
order by dropper_id;
```

Second statement:

```
select count(*) from random_selection where dropper_id is null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries are not the same so your record count would not be the same.  You first query is joining on 2 tables and your second query is only getting the record count of one table.  Plus you have `WHERE` clauses on your first query that are not on the second.

If you want your second query to return the same number of records then you have to use the same tables and where clause that you have in the first

```
select count(*) 
from random_selection, dropper_city_brk_2
where random_selection.ozip3 = dropper_city_brk_2.zip3
and dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id <> 10002
and random_selection.dropper_id is null
```

EDIT:

```
select count(*) 
from random_selection 
INNER JOIN dropper_city_brk_2
  ON random_selection.ozip3 = dropper_city_brk_2.zip3
WHERE dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id <> 10002
  and random_selection.dropper_id is null
```

Here is a [visual explanation of JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) that might be helpful as a reference.

Comment: Well, techichnically, _might_ not be the same

Comment: correct, they might not be the same. but you have one query joining with one table and the second isn't. that is a big difference.

Comment: the 2nd query should be returning the number or rows that are in the first query, all i want is to add dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id to the result where random_selection.ozip3 = dropper_city_brk_2.zip3

Comment: @Mike your query structures are totally different between the 1st and 2nd. you are using different tables and where clauses.

Comment: `select count(*)
from random_selection, dropper_city_brk_2
where random_selection.ozip3 = dropper_city_brk_2.zip3
and dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id <> 10002
and random_selection.dropper_id is null
order by dropper_id;`  should be returning the same number of rows, the only difference is im adding the dropper_id from another table

Comment: @Mike I think you need to edit your post and add some sample data. By posting some sample data of what you want before and after that would be helpful.

Comment: @Mike you say that 'the only difference is im adding the dropper_id from another table'.  This is the key to your problem, you are changing your query by doing this.

Comment: so how do i successfully join the 2 tables? there shouldnt be more results by assigning the dropper_id to the corresponding zip3

Comment: @Mike I edited my post with another version of the query.  I don't fully understand what you are asking for.  Can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "Why is the second query not returning the number of rows given by the first query"? If so, then it's probably because of the cross join and the extra where clauses in the first query.

If, for some reason, you think that these entirely different-looking queries **should** yield the same number of rows, then you'll have to tell us how your data is structured.

Comment: i agree that we probably need some data.

Comment: `select *
from random_selection
and random_selection.dropper_id is null`;
im just trying to add dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id to the results, the common field is random_selection.ozip3 and dropper_city_brk_w.zip3

Comment: All of this is prettymuch gobbeldygook **until you explain the structure of your tables**.  What columns are there?  How do the columns relate?  Are there any primary keys?  Foreign keys?  Other constraints?